# Installing window AC in single hung window

Tags: windows

I am installing windows ac in a single hung window. Problem is that bottom support of AC is about 1/4th inch wider than 2 lips of window. Also outside lip is 1/4 inch higher than inside lip.[image: window]

Answer (score 0):

Place a board in the space between the inner and outer "rims" of the window and rest the ac unit on that. You would round the corners so the board can be rotated into place.